# Array Lists in java

Tags: java, arraylist

Is there a way to remove all empty cells in an `ArrayList` by just a built in function call? I saw `trimToSize` but I didn't really get what it meant.

For example, suppose I have an array that contains `{1,2,3}`. Lets say I say `array.remove(1)` so now the array looks like `{1,null,3}`. Is there a function to call to make it converge to be `{1,3}`?

I know I can hard code a method to do that for me but I was just curious.

Comment: Are you talking about an array (eg., int[] foo = ...) or an ArrayList (eg., ArrayList<Integer> = ...)?

Comment: The word `ArrayList` is not a random Java term representing an array. It's a real Java class with real methods! Start here to learn about it: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html

Comment: I think trimToSize is doing just what you want. It set's the capacity to be the same as the size.

Comment: An edit to this question changed it to refer to ArrayList, but from the original question it was not clear whether au789 was talking about an array or an ArrayList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an ArrayList, you don't need to worry about compacting the array after removing an element from it. The ArrayList class takes care of this kind of housekeeping.

If you are using an array, you could use the [Commons Lang ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html) class. The removeElement methods in this class simplify removing an element from an array and shifting all elements after it to the left.

Answer (score 7):

That's [exactly what `remove` does](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29).

> Removes the element at the specified
>   position in this list. Shifts any
>   subsequent elements to the left
>   (subtracts one from their indices).

Now, if you're talking about arrays, not `ArrayList`, the answer is no.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to accept your answer here shortly. I'm relatively new so I didn't know array lists automatically handled any shifting.

Answer (score 1):

In [here](http://www.mhaller.de/archives/12-How-to-remove-all-null-elements-from-a-Collection.html) you find a post that shows how to remove all null elements in a Collection

```
    List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    myList.add(1);
    myList.add(2);
    myList.add(null);
    myList.add(3);
    myList.add(null);
    myList.add(4);

    System.out.println("With null values");
    for(Integer i: myList)
        System.out.println(i);

    myList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));              

    System.out.println("After deleting null values");
    for(Integer i: myList)
        System.out.println(i);
```

Output:
**With null values**
1
2
null
3
null
4

**After deleting null values**
1
2
3
4

Comment: +1 for the `myList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));` line. You learn every day a new thing in SO :)